# VBA Input Box will not close

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a code shown below for entering a password to have the code start. I am a VBA noob so please go easy on me.

**Issue:** When the input box prompt appears it works fine if the password is correct. If it is incorrect you are given more opportunities to enter it again but lets say you do not know the password and want to close the window, you cannot. The "x" option and cancel options will just cause the input box prompt to refresh rather than closing the window. How can I set the window up to close?

Here is the code in written form:

```
    Sub Pword()

        Dim Ans As Boolean
        Const Pword As String = "black2"

        Ans = False

        Do While Ans = False
            If InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password") = Pword Then
                Ans = True
            End If
        Loop

Sheets("Workshop").Range("B15:B20") = ""
Sheets("Workshop").Range("B24:B29") = ""
Sheets("Workshop").Range("B33:B35") = ""
Sheets("Workshop").Range("E5:E11") = ""
Sheets("Workshop").Range("E15:E26") = ""
Sheets("Workshop").Range("H5:H17") = ""

MsgBox "All data has been cleared."


End Sub
```

Comment: Not to answer the question, but just an FYI you can group ranges `Sheets("Workshop").Range("B15:B20", "B24:B29", "B33:B35").Value = ""`etc

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check to see if it's an empty string, like this:

```
    Dim sResult As String
    Do While Ans = False
        sResult = InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password")
        If sResult = Pword Then
            Ans = True
        ElseIf sResult = "" Then
            Exit Do ' or Exit Sub depending on what you want to happen afterwards
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: or `sResult = vbNullString`

Answer (score 4):

If you need to consider an empty string as a valid input value, the only way to check if the `InputBox` was *actually* cancelled isn't to compare its result with `vbNullString` or `""` (both will be `True`).

So you can use the (undocumented) `StrPtr` function to determine if the `InputBox` call returned a legit empty string, or if it was actively cancelled *with the [X] or [Cancel] button*:

```
Dim result As String
result = InputBox(...)
If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then
    ' inputbox was cancelled
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' todo: validate result
End If
```

Combine that with the other answers to get a reliable "retry" mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

@braX suggestion is an excellent solution.
Also, you can limit the attemps to `n` in this case I limit the attempts to 3

```
 Dim sResult As String
 Dim Attmp As Integer
 Attmp = 0
    Do While Ans = False
        sResult = InputBox("Please enter password to continue.", "Enter Password")
        If sResult = Pword Then
            Ans = True
        ElseIf sResult = "" Then
            Attmp = Attmp + 1
            If Attmp = 3 Then 
                Msgbox "Maximum attempts reached."
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```